# How to manage applications

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, software-uninstall

I am dualbooting Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 for about a year. My intention is to completely step away from the Windows environment, but I keep returning to Windows. Mainly because installing and managing applications seem to take so much time.

**Installing applications**

I cheer when an app is packaged in .deb file. But when I have to install .tar.gz files I become confused about where to run the file from and how to assign the correct privileges. I am running my main apps from a different partition than /home. So what would be the proper way to install applications?

**Uninstalling applications**

I really like in Windows how you can get a list from installed apps and just deinstall them. Applications that are not packaged in .deb files seem to not be listed in the ubuntu software center. How can I keep track of my applications and de-install them in an easy way.

**Installing and Uninstalling from command line**

A great advantage of Linux seem to be the apt-get install things. But it can be dangerous if I do not know what I am doing. Often apps require dependencies and I install them. When I install another app that require the same dependencies, I do not have to install them. When I want to uninstall an app completely, how do I keep track that its dependencies is being used by another app at the same time?

I am desperate to step off Windows, but these issues results me into spending a lot of time configuring my Ubuntu desktop, which is keeping me off the actual tasks I need to do. I am about to invest into an OSX machine, but I really want to reconsider Ubuntu desktop. Does anyone have the perfect guide for me?

Comment: The .tar.gz files, are they source packages or binary packages?

Comment: Sometimes binary, sometimes source. It differs.

Comment: I really hope you can help me!

Comment: for the source packages, you might want to look into `checkinstall`.

Answer (score 0):

it's totally fine that you are new to UBUNTU...

You do know about "[Software Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center)" in UBUNTU....

Go here : [SynapticHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto). This article has all answers you needed.

More over to do it totally using Terminal:  [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

I hope this will help you alot.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding .tar.gz files and where to run the file. Usual place for such not-managed-with-apt software is /opt, e.g. Google chrome does this, or Eclipse.